# Disable all animation in Shell Navigation of Xamarin 4.0+ (iOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, xamarin.forms.shell

Is there a way to disable the animation on page changes in a Xamarin.Forms App made with Xamarin.Forms 4.0+ and using the new Shell Navigation?

When using the function `Shell.GoToAsync(ShellNavigationState, Boolean)` it is possible to pass `false` as for the second parameter `animate`.

But what about the FlyoutItems navigated to from the flyout menu? There it is not me calling GoToAsync or anything, it is done by the framework. How can I disable animation for these elements?

**Edit:** As commented by user Depechie, the default behaviour of this is animated = false. Now I realised, it **only animates in iOS**. iOS is doing an Alphablending when switching the page with flyout menu. Android is just changing page, showing a hard flicker.

Comment: How do you do the pages changes with animation and pass false as parameter? Please provide more details.

Comment: @WendyZang I added exact signature of the method for manual navigation, but it is not very relevant cause it is not the function I want to call. I want to disable all animations of page navigation.

Comment: If I read the Shell code correctly a MenuFlyoutItem would eventually trigger a GoToAsync itself, but already has false for the animation bool https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/1dd94d6bae28c35b57acf49ef9b299e56351222f/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Shell/ShellSection.cs#L82 so if this is not actually the case in your test. Maybe log an issue on Xamarin.Forms github?